# Cannot find utxo using cardano-cli on docker cardano-node preprod

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, docker, query

I am trying to follow the project based learning program but get stucked here:
https://plutuspbl.io/modules/102/1023

I started the docker container for cardano-node (https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/cardano-node) like this:

```
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3-configs
docker run -e NETWORK=preprod inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3-configs
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket
```

**Updated according to previous answer but still not working:**

```
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-node:8.1.2
docker run -e NETWORK=preprod inputoutput/cardano-node:8.1.2
```

I created my address as described (https://plutuspbl.io/modules/102/1022):

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
--babbage-era \
--testnet-magic 1 \
--tx-in $UTXO_IN \
--tx-out $SENDERADDRESS+$LOVELACE_TO_SEND \
--change-address $SENDERADDRESS \
--out-file simple-tx.raw

cardano-cli transaction sign \
--signing-key-file $SENDERKEY \
--testnet-magic 1 \
--tx-body-file simple-tx.raw \
--out-file simple-tx.signed

cardano-cli transaction submit \
--tx-file simple-tx.signed \
--testnet-magic 1
```

Sending ADA using Lace in Preprod works. I can see the transaction here:
https://preprod.cardanoscan.io/address/00afb85707bc11b8a018610da4b79f73d2c3553dedce2a8a414bd2eb974326c013bb1e3aae31194b06e23222a9e47e481db054447fcfae217f

But I cannot find the utxo using

```
cardano-cli query utxo --testnet-magic 1 --address $SENDERADDRESS
```

As SENDERADDRESS I tried the generated wallet address (as shown in the lecture) and also my lace address but both are just showing empty results (line of dashes).

If I was using the wrong network not even sending the ADA from Lace should have worked right? Any suggestions what might be wrong?

**Update: Turned out I just did not wait long enough. The block of the container tip must of course be greater than the block containing the transaction:**

```
cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an old node version that can't cross the Babbage hard fork. Please update to 8.1.2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested again using

<pre><code>
docker pull inputoutput/cardano-node:8.1.2
docker run -e NETWORK=preprod inputoutput/cardano-node:8.1.2
</code></pre>

Again no result using the cli but I can find it here: https://preprod.cardanoscan.io/address/00b52857af1ed681cde138710077c887931fbd31c4718543f0a2bd2d7d83d03c257a1c1fe6763034537ec9c1a0c8261054a7909d527f4ce87d

Any suggestions? Also from the documentation I expected a version like 8.1.2-configs but it seems 1.35.3-configs was the only tag with a -configs postfix. Are the configs now included in every release?